Is there any way to get Blender onto a school Chromebook
I recently got into Blender. and wanted to use it more often, including when I go to school. I wanted to know if there is any way around the ChromeOS administration. If it was my own machine, I would install it through the Linux subsystem, but the school administrations have that blocked.

There is no official version for chrome, blender need more resources than a chrome book needs. And also, the site is not meant for questions like this but for question on how to solve problems within Blender software

Ok well thanks anyway

Hello, Rattyarmy ,welcome. ... Normally, (hello, @Emir) would be right about the question.. but this is an edge case, IMO: 'Is there any way to run Blender on ChromeOS?" seems fair, in the circumstances.  I'm glad TheLabCat has done their best to answer, and hope you find a way through, maybe by negotiation with the school.. Blender could be  great incentive to  learn some important areas of maths, art, and priogramming.

In short, we can’t say. This site is more for asking for help with Blender itself, but this is a problem with the idea of using Blender at school, which is being blocked by something outside of Blender: School policy. I might recommend you ask your art teacher, or whoever gave you the Chromebook to use, if there is a way you can use Blender at school. Don’t try to sneak in through a back door on the system, though. That would almost certainly lead to trouble. I would note that there is a version of Blender on Steam, but I’ve never used ChromeOS so I don’t know if that helps you.

Thanks, I did try to download Blender through steam but it just turned into a massive mess, I'll be sure to ask some people and see what I can do. Thanks, have a good day
